# tomcat 6 maxThreads setting doesn't work

Tags: tomcat6, threadpool

We have a pretty hefty application running on tomcat. I am trying to do some simple load testing on the simplest servlet. 
I have a simple script that sends 200 background curl commands to that servlet. Many of those commands get "connection reset by peer". When I use VisualVM to monitor tomcat I see it starts with about 70 threads (some are our own thread pools such as for Quartz) and when I run this script the number of threads will go up to something like 170 but no more. It seems like no matter how I set maxThreads for the 8080 connector, I am getting the same results. 
From threads prospective, my machine can handle around 2,030 Java threads per one JVM before getting out of memory error, so that's not the problem.

I saw there are about 5 other threads on similar topics but none helps.

Thank you.